# Navigation rules with xpage returning to another application does not work

Tags: xpages

I'm calling an xpage from a portal xpage and would like to return to the portal on success or cancel.  I've set the next page(success or cancel) rule to Previous page.  When I test with a simple cancel button it does not return to the previous page.  In summary Application A opens a page in Application B in edit mode. When I click on a cancel button in Application B it does not return to Application A.

```
<xp:this.navigationRules>
<xp:navigationRule
    outcome="xsp-success"
    viewId="$$PreviousPage"></xp:navigationRule>
</xp:this.navigationRules>
```

I then tried with sessionScope variable with the return URL but the sessionScope variable does not seem to be available in Application B.

I must be missing something really basic.  Can anyone give me a hand ?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation rules apply only per application. "Special" rules like *$$HomePage* will always return to the application root, and *$$PreviousPage* will return to the last page stored in *sessionScope*. The last page in *sessionScope* is also application specific, that's why this is not working.

Try to open your application B with an URL parameter and store this parameter in the *sessionScope* of application B. Instead of using a navigation rule, you can simply do a  redirect if a user cancels.